# Pass data to child template in cart-items of checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, magento2.2, knockout

My site is a market place site where vendors(sellers can sell their product).

Now i want to customize the to group items in cart by each vendor like this:
http://prntscr.com/hmsam6

**checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<item name="cart_groups" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart-groups</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart_groups/cart-items</item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="thumbnail" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail</item>
                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before_details</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal</item>
                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after_details</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

cart-group.js

```
define([
'ko',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
'uiComponent',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'], function (ko, totals, Component, stepNavigator, quote) {
'use strict';

return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/cart-groups'
    },
    groups: window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData,
    getGroups:function(){
        var tempGroups = this.groups;
        var arr = Object.keys(tempGroups).map(function (key) { return tempGroups[key]; });

        return arr;
    },
    /**
     * Returns bool value for items block state (expanded or not)
     *
     * @returns {*|Boolean}
     */
    isItemsBlockExpanded: function () {
        return quote.isVirtual() || stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
    },
    /**
     * Returns cart items qty
     *
     * @returns {Number}
     */
    getItemsQty: function () {
        return parseFloat(this.totals['items_qty']);
    },

    /**
     * Returns count of cart line items
     *
     * @returns {Number}
     */
    getCartLineItemsCount: function () {
        return parseInt(totals.getItems()().length, 10);
    },
});});
```

cart-group.html

```
<div class="block items-in-cart"
 data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': isItemsBlockExpanded()}}">
<div class="title" data-role="title">
    <strong role="heading">
        <translate args="'Item in Cart'" if="getCartLineItemsCount() === 1"/>
        <translate args="'Items in Cart'" if="getCartLineItemsCount() > 1"/>
    </strong>
</div>
<div class="content minicart-items" data-role="content">
    <div class="minicart-items-wrapper overflowed">
        <each args="getGroups()">
            <p class="checkout-vendor-shop-name" data-bind="text: vendor_shop_name"></p>
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.elems() -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </each>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is here:

```
            <each args="getGroups()">
            <p class="checkout-vendor-shop-name" data-bind="text: vendor_shop_name"></p>
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.elems() -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </each>
```

How can i pass data to child template with each data in this loop: getGroups() array. Right now it is all the data in quote, and it is duplicated 2 times

Comment: Yes. Magento 2.2.x. But it is related to knockoutjs, which i am not familiar with. Can you give me some hint to go ?

Comment: have you fond solution?

Comment: @ToànTam have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430976/can-i-pass-a-variable-in-a-template-binding

So something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: getGroups">
    <p class="checkout-vendor-shop-name" data-bind="text: vendor_shop_name"></p>
    <!-- ko foreach: $parent.elems() -->
        <!-- ko template: { name: getTemplate(), templateOptions: {myvar: $data} } --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```